# How to access dynamically updated drop down list in Python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I have a HTML form which dynamically updates two drop down list values depending on what is selected in the 3rd drop down list using jQuery.

Using Python (CGI), how can I access the selected value of the two dynamic drop down list.

**HTML file:**

```
<body>
<form action="/cgi-bin/ISPsetup.py" method="get" name="theform">
<table cellspacing="20">
<tr>
<td>Site: </td>
<td>
  <select id="site">
    <option val="va1">va1</option>
    <option val="va2">va2</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Cap1: </td>
  <td>
    <select id="cap1">
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Cap2: </td>
  <td>
    <select id="cap2">
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>
</body>
```

**site.js:**

```
va1odd = new Array('va1-isp-cap1-01','va1-isp-cap2-01','va1-rdc-isp-cap3-01','va1-rdc-isp-cap4-01');
va1even = new Array('va1-isp-cap1-02','va1-isp-cap2-02','va1-rdc-isp-cap3-02','va1-rdc-isp-cap4-02');
va2odd = new Array('va2-rdc-isp-cap-01');
va2even = new Array('va2-rdc-isp-cap-02');

populateSelect();

$(function() {

      $('#site').change(function(){
        populateSelect();
    });

});


function populateSelect(){
    cat=$('#site').val();
    $('#cap1').html('');
    $('#cap2').html('');


    if(cat=='va1'){
        va1odd.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#cap1').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
         va1even.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#cap2').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

    if(cat=='va2'){
        va2odd.forEach(function(t) {
            $('#cap1').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
        va2even.forEach(function(t) {
            $('#cap2').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

}
```

ISPsetup.py:

```
import cgi, cgitb

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

site = form.getvlaue('site')
```

Comment: html form and jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/r7MN9/1999/

Comment: form.getvalue('cap1') works.